Isomorphism of restricted representations implies isomorphism of representations
Given some representations $V_1$ and $V_2$ of a finite group $G$ (over the complex numbers), is there some general rule to tell when $Res(V_1) \cong Res(V_2) \implies V_1 \cong V_2$ for representations restricted to some subgroup $H$? Im especially interested in the case of symmetric group representations.
Im assuming this has something to do with the uniqueness of how representations restrict and could imagine that at least for $S_n$ with the correspondence with young diagrams and the branching rule there is some regularity.

You mean isomorphic right?

@MartinBrandenburg right, thanks.
